# Only first attachment is sended through php mailer

Tags: php, javascript, phpmailer

I am making a form to upload multiple attachments through multiple upload boxes:
I am adding the file uploads through a javascript function , to attach more file upload boxes ,up to 5 boxes:

```
<input type="file" name="attachment[]" size="30"
onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';" />
 <div id="moreUploads"></div>
 <div id="moreUploadsLink" style="display:none;">
 <a href="javascript:addFileInput();">Attach another File</a></div>
```

On a selection , through javascript, it asks for "Attach another file" and on clicking this, it provides up to 5 upload files,

The problem is when i try to send the mail with all attachments, only first attach is sended:
The loop to send is

```
   $numFiles = count($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
   for ($i = 0; $i < $numFiles; ++$i) 
{
 $target_path = "uploads/";
     $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i]);
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path)) {
     echo "the file ".basename($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i])." has been uploaded
     <br/>";
 }
 $mail->AddAttachment($target_path);
 }
```

Please any body help